# Applications of the Closed graph theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

In functional analysis a famous theorem states that: if $X, Y$ are Banach spaces and $T: X \to Y$ is a linear operator, $T$ is continous if and only if the graph $\Gamma_T:={(x,Tx), x \in X}$ is closed in the product topology. Do you know some nice application of this theorem? Thank you!!

Answer (score 11):

“Continuity of a linear map $T:\mathscr X\to\mathscr Y$ means that if $x_n \to x$, then $T(x_n) \to T(x)$, whereas closedness means that if $x_n\to x$ and $T(x_n) \to y$ then $y = T(x)$. Thus the significance of the closed graph theorem is that in verifying that $T(x_n) \to T(x)$ when $x_n \to x$, we may assume that $T(x_n)$ converges to *something*, and we need only to show that the limit is the right thing. This frequently saves a lot of trouble.” ([Folland, 1999, p. 163](http://books.google.com/books?id=wI4fAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=hu&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Answer (score 4):

1. It is always stated at the beginning when one introduces theory of
   unbounded operators, to justify that a closed linear operator $A
       \colon Dom(A) \subset X \rightarrow Y$ such that $Dom(A) = X$ is
   bounded; which in fact is just a reformulation of CGT.
2. There is an elementary proof of the fact that for any algebraic
   isomorphism  $\pi \colon \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$
   between standard operator algebras $\mathcal{A} $ and $\mathcal{B}$
   over normed spaces $X$ and $Y$, respectively, there is a linear
   continuous isomorphism $T\colon X \rightarrow Y$ such that $$ \pi(A)
       = TAT^{-1} \ \ \text{for all} A \in \mathcal{A}.$$ In particular, $\pi$ is continuous. It uses CGT.

   The proof can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-11/S0002-9939-06-08375-4/S0002-9939-06-08375-4.pdf)
3. You might also want to look at [LINK](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1964-015-03/S0002-9939-1964-0164239-3/S0002-9939-1964-0164239-3.pdf).
4. An article about CGT in various categories is also interesting and can be found [Here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/the-closed-graph-theorem-in-various-categories/).